# Populating a calculated field in textbox with selection in combobox

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2003, calculated-field

Thanks for the help in advance. I'm not familiar with the functions...

I've got a subform that contains a list of fields like type, amount and units. I will like to calculate the total amount based on the selected type. By doing so, I tried using coding, but encountered various errors.

Firstly, "Runtime Error '3078':" The Microsoft Jet Database Engine cannot find the inpute table/ query '50000'.

My code for this is:

```
If Me.cmbTOL1 = "Type B" Then
Me.txtC1 = (DMax(Me.txtAmt1, 50000) * 0.055) / Me.txtNoofUnits1
End If
```

Secondly, "Runtime Error '2450':" Mircosoft Access can't find form "frmInformation" referred to in a macro expression or visual basic code.

My code for this is:

```
If Me.cmbTOL1 = "Type M" Then
Me.txtC1 = (DMax(Me.txtAmt1, (2 * [Forms]![frmInformation]![GrossAmt])) * 0.015) / Me.txtNoofUnits1
End If
```

Edits:

I'm trying to get the value [GrossAmt] from the frmInformation. Is there another way besides [Forms]![frmInformation]![GrossAmt] to retrieve the value?

I don't really get the DMax() function... but I've changed my code to this...

```
If Me.cmbTOL1 = "Type B" Then 
   If Me.txtAmt1 > 50000 Then 
   Me.txtC1 = (Me.txtAmt1 * 0.055) / Me.txtNoofUnits1 
   Else 
   Me.txtC1 = (50000 * 0.055) / Me.txtNoofUnits1 
   End If 
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

From [DMin, DMax Functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dmin-dmax-functions-HA001228826.aspx), the syntax is:

```vba
DMax(expr, domain[, criteria])
```

The second argument, *domain*, is supposed to be "*A string expression identifying the set of records that constitutes the domain. It can be a table name or a query name for a query that does not require a parameter.*"

But your code gives `DMax()` numerical values for the *domain* argument:

```vba
DMax(Me.txtAmt1, 50000)
DMax(Me.txtAmt1, (2 * [Forms]![frmInformation]![GrossAmt]))
```

I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.  However, if you use `DMax()`, you must give it the name of a table or query as the *domain* argument.  And `Me.txtAmt1` should be the name of a field, or expression based on a field, in the *domain*.

The error message which complains that *Access can't find form "frmInformation"* could be because the form is not open (therefore not present in the Forms collection), the name is misspelled, or it is actually a subform contained in another form.

You didn't explain what happens with the code update in your question.  Tell us what happens when you type this line in the Immediate window  and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```vba
? [Forms]![frmInformation]![GrossAmt]
```

You can open the Immediate window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>.  The form, `frmInformation`, should be open in Form View when you type the above line in the Immediate window.

You can check the names, as Access sees them, of all open forms from the Immediate window like this:

```vba
for each f in forms : ? f.Name : next
```

Comment: The runtime error appears... "Runtime Error '2450':" Mircosoft Access can't find form "frmInformation" referred to in a macro expression or visual basic code.

I've doubled check the form name... It's correct... Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: The form i'm using for the above is a subform... frmInformation is the main form...

Comment: If frmInformation is the *main* form and is open in Form View, it should be found with [Forms]![frmInformation]

Comment: How do i keep the subform open in the mainform? I'm trying to get the [GrossAmt] from the mainform to do calculation in the subform (as of above).